# post-installation WSUS windows server 2016

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, wsus

I have a WSUS in server 2016 and I deleted this services, but now I needing put this services on this server again, I did this points:
I Uninstall WSUS and on powershell remove the WID:
uninstall-windowsfeature -name windows-internal-database
I remove the WSUS site from IIS manager.
I Restart the server, then go to the windows folder and delete the WID folder.

I delete the wsus file from "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\MMC"
and I Reinstall WSUS
when I Installa the services of WSUS I don't have a problem but when I do post-installation it stays in a state of charge for a long time and there is no longer a breakthrough .
and only stays there.

[image]